# React-table loads slower with live API data than with mock data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

Currently when I load a React-table locally with ~200 rows of mock data the performance is smooth, but when I do the same thing locally with ~200 rows of data from the API performance takes a huge hit. I'm fine with the actual search taking a hit, but currently, every time I try to navigate to the next page of the table or navigate out of/into the component itself the lag is very noticeable. The API is made through Spring, but it only appears to be accessed when the search is initially executed.

I've tried tracking the call with console logs to see where in the code the issue is occurring, it appears that the issue exists within react-table itself, but I'm still unsure of why the issue only occurs with data pulled from the API.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal whenever you are fetching big data. There will be slight lag while fetching data from API. Also share your code. So, I can go through it.